# Configure Einstein Chat Bots to show Knowledge Base Articles

Tags: einstein, lightning-knowledge

I used the Cookbook(http://go.pardot.com/l/349921/2018-06-13/gq59) to get Knowledge Articles into my bot.But it's not working...

The problem that I'm having is that my bot seems to have no rights for knowledgearticleversion.

I see the following error in the bot logs: "An Apex error occurred: System.QueryException: sObject type 'knowledgearticleversion' is not supported. "

Because when I execute the code in anonymous, it works just fine.

Has someone else stumbled upon this problem and found a solution for this?

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer myself, way easier than I thought.

You just have to give the rights in the permission set for bots.
"Read" and "View All" rights for the Knowledge Object.

With Knowledge Object, I mean the object that is created from the one Article Type you still have left after changing to Knowledge for Lightning.

Comment: Here's how: Go to **Setup** > **Permission Sets** > `sfdc.chatbot.service.permset` > **Object Settings** > Select `Knowledge` (first one for me) -> Give `Read`,`View All` permissions, then save ... [source](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bot_cookbook.meta/bot_cookbook/bot_cookbook_gather_customer_info.htm#apex-perm-info)